# WS2812B-8 Strip has two grounds. Is one a signal ground?

Tags: ws2812b

I'm running 5 x WS2812B-8 RGB LED strips off an ESP32.

The strips have 4 pads on each end: (from top to bottom)

- GND - Is this signal ground?
- In / Out - Signal
- VCC - 5V
- GND - Is this power ground?

I plan on running VCC and power ground directly off their own voltage regulator and the ESP32 on its own own regulator off the same battery, so their grounds are already tied. If the other ground is a signal ground, it goes directly to the ESP32?

Is 18AWG for the power wires and 26AWG for signal and ground adequate for 40 LEDs total?

[image]

Comment: We can't know what LED strips you are using. Can you edit that info to question? The WS2812B LEDs have only four pins with only one ground so it is unknown how the two grounds are connected - maybe they just provide you with two to allow using more than one ground wire or simply allow for using differet pinouts. We also don't know how much current you are going to push with the LEDs (all in series at full brightness, or all parallel at reduced brightness) and how long wires you are going to use (1m or 1000m), so it is hard to say if the wire AWG is enough. You need the manual for LED strips.

Comment: @Justme As mentioned in the question, I am using a "WS2812B-8", that's how the strip is marked. For the other questions, I'm using 5 strips, 40 LEDs. It's battery powered (2x18650) the max wire length is 8" and the total length of the entire series is <1m.

Comment: Yes but you can't find which product it is if you googe for "WS2812B-8". You need to tell which exact product it is, where you bought it, is there a product page with datasheet and manual for it? You could also take a photo and post it here to see how the grounds are connected

Comment: @justme There is no documentation for it, but updating the post with a picture of it is a good idea.